# Ползунок в свойствах скрипта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать ползунок в свойствах скрипта в Unity?
Например при значении

```
Public bool
```

в скрипте
, в его свойствах появляется чекбокс
при

```
Public int или float
```

появляется поле для ввода цифр. 
А как сделать ползунок, ограниченный минимальным и максимальным значением?
Например, чтобы сделать из -1 до +1 удобное изменение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Range (3f, 10f)]
public float test;
```

И в инспекторе появляется ползунок

Answer (score 0):

Без f

```
[Range (3, 10)]
public float test;
```